# NPN_Evaluate blocks the ui while camera preview is running

Tags: npapi

If i execute NPN_Evaluate in plugin, when camera preview is running, the whole ui gets blocked and does not take any input from the user. My understanding was am doing NPN_Evaluate on a wrong NPObject which i get using `NPN_GetValue( Npp, NPNVWindowNPObject, &sWindowObj)`. The script am trying to evaluate is like this:
`"confirm (\'Do you want to Capture Image\');"`
which shows a popup above camera preview asking to capture image.

Answer (score 1):

ok guys... I found the problem. I was trying to evaluate the javascript from a native call from java to jni. when i changed the thread of execution, the problem was solved.